# Codeigniter and uploading zip files

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-manipulation, gdlib

I am currently building a backend to a site using the codeigniter framework, I have hit a bit of a problem, I needing a way to allow the user to upload a zipped folder of images, on completing the form, zipped folder must be unzipped, and the files need to be moved to a folder else where on the server, have thumbnail version of each image created and have there file name add to the DB, and also if the images are for a content type that does not already exist then I need to make a directory with that content type.

I know there is an upload class in Codeigniter, but I am not sure that, that has the capabilities do what I need, I could really do with some advice please?

Thanks

Comment: this is quite a broad question and a specific problem. With what part are you having problems with?

Comment: The particular problem i am having is that I cannot work out a way to unpack the zip and cycle through all the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wont be able to do any of the image or file checking using the Upload class. The upload class will let you accept the file and check it is a ZIP but that's as far as it will go.

From there, [unzip](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Unzip/) the file and just do some simple PHP on the files to check they are the right type and make your folders etc. I would put this logic in a new library to keep it separated correctly.

Comment: Thanks phil, think that might just what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Hi, the link you provided is broken. Can you please update it?

Comment: That package is here: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-unzip I'd recommend you use anything else than this. Even if you're using CodeIgniter, you should be going to Packagist and installing generic packages instead. Try this https://packagist.org/search/?tags=unzip

Answer (score 4):

As Jan pointed out, this is a broad question (like 3 or 4 questions). I'm not up to date with the CodeIgniter framework but **to Unzip the files** you can do something like this:

```
function Unzip($source, $destination)
{
    if (extension_loaded('zip') === true)
    {
        if (file_exists($source) === true)
        {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();

            if ($zip->open($source) === true)
            {
                $zip->extractTo($destination);
            }

            return $zip->close();
        }
    }

    return false;
}

Unzip('/path/to/uploaded.zip', '/path/to/extract/');
```